# TSQL - Create an Alert in SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a start date time and end date time. I want to create an alert at 2 hrs from the start and at 3 hrs another one but stop at end  date time.

Can anyone help me, please?

Start time : Sept.8,2013 9 am alert at 11 am (yellow), 12 noon red and stop at end time 2:30 pm:
I want to see the data in a color code.E.g. from 2 to 3 yellow color and after 3 red color and it will stop at end time.

Basically, I want to write a sql query.  It can be a SSRS or Web service. It's real-time dashboard.

Comment: what kind of alert? a warning when executing your query? a windows desktop alert? a message showing on the web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

I converted your time frame to minutes.

[dt_DATE_TIME] = the time of the event

dbo.tbl_YOUR_TABLE = the name of the table the field [dt_DATE_TIME]
   is in

```
select
    [dt_DATE_TIME] as 'date time',
    case
        when getdate() < dateadd(n,120,[dt_DATE_TIME]) then 'green'
        when getdate() between dateadd(n,120,[dt_DATE_TIME]) and dateadd(n,180,[dt_DATE_TIME]) then 'yellow'
        when getdate() between dateadd(n,180,[dt_DATE_TIME]) and dateadd(n,330,[dt_DATE_TIME]) then 'red'
        when getdate() > dateadd(n,330,[dt_DATE_TIME]) then ' '
    end as 'color'
from
    dbo.tbl_YOUR_TABLE
```

Comment: Hi, It's not exactly that I wanted but it helped me to get  my work done. May be my question was confusing. Anyway, Thanks for help.